# Fn keys behaving differently

Tags: windows-10, fn-key

I've been using this Windows computer for a couple of years now, and I'm suddenly seeing a lot of strange behaviour on my Fn keys. It started when I tried to escape full-screen mode by pressing F11, but then it opened my file explorer instead. Then I soon realized every key was remapped. Some of my keys open apps, while others change volume. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the F lock, but I could be wrong. But the problem is, I don't *have* a 'Fn' key. Nor a 'Fn Lock' key.

What I've tried:

- Disabling GeForce & Xbox game overlays.
- Using On-Screen Keyboard in Windows and pressing the 'Fn' key with other key comboniations (like Fn + Caps Lock, Fn + Esc) to disable F lock.
- Entering Bios and switch the 'Action Keys Mode' (but i couldn't find the option so i guess  this doesnt count)

Here's every function of these F keys I've found so far: 
`F1`: Opens Groove Music by Microsoft
`F2`: Decreases Volume
`F3`: Increases Volume
`F4`: Mutes Volume

`F5`: Skips Video/Song on Youtube & Spotify? Not too sure.
`F6`: Plays Previous Video/Song. Also not very sure.
`F7`: Pauses Current Video/Song.
`F8`: No very sure, but I think it Switches Between differnt services. (like YT, Spotify but havent tested it on others)

`F9`: Opens Google Chrome
`F10`: Oepns Mail from Microsoft
`F11`: Opens File Explorer
`F12`: Doesn't do anything yet, but it doesnt open up Google's DevTools so I don't really know what it's mapped to.

Windows Specs:
Edition:        Windows 10 Home
Version:        21H2
Installed on:   ‎12/‎12/‎2021
OS build:       19044.3086
Experience:     Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Device Specs:
Device name:    WX20211030-51
Processor:      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz   4.00 GHz
Installed RAM:  16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
Device ID:      18A0E26C-249E-4EA5-ABC4-5B2D9ED24597
Product ID:     00326-10000-00000-AA826
System type:    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch:  No pen or touch input is available for this display

**TLDR**: I have Fn-Lock On (pretty sure) but I don't have a Fn Key and need to turn it off.

**EDIT**:
Not certain how I fixed it, but after some weird manuvering, keyboard  unplugging & Fn combinations, but now my keys beahve as normal. I don't know how either. So I guess my problem is fixed?

**EDIT 2**: Should I post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

What's the OEM?  Fn lock and hotkey default behavior modifications are typically found in OEM system utilities (or sometimes within BIOS/UEFI), but this could possibly vary, and honestly I've never seen it outside of notebook or mobile builds.  Does this state persist even after fully power cycling?  Note that there is a possible distinction that you might need to determine behind the current symptoms: **Fn lock** makes F key inputs invoke the hotkey functions directly and inversely trigger F-key inputs when the Fn key is in the down-state.  It's possible that for some reason your system is erroneously registering that an Fn key is actively being actuated in the down-state.  I would check with a keyboard hook/logger that the latter is not the case (also, disable any other keyboard input devices in device manager), and unplug your mouse and any other USB peripherals and dongles, before toggling the virtual Fn key on and then off again.  If the behavior persists (and especially if it inverts key functions when active), then I would look in the direction of system configuration or utilities (in which case, try starting in safe-mode and see if it persists there or not).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are right that your system changed to the "Media Key Layout" as default.

1. Have a look in your (USFI-)BIOS. There might be a switch for the default behavior of the Fn-Keys.
   The unexpected change might have been triggered by a BIOS reset.
   This BIOS reset might have been triggered by purpose, by BIOS upgrade or an error.
2. Possibly your system might have a manufacturer's system tool for Windows that also can configure some (UEFI-)BIOS settings while running the operating system using a graphical user interface.
   Perhaps you tried it and accidently changed some settings.
3. Depending on your keyboard, there might be some keyboard driver and software that also can trigger the media key layout.